# I am getting an error "cannot find module" when attempting to put in "node index.js"

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\The_T\Downloads\generative-art-node-main\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

any idea how to pass this step? it is my last step before it generates my NFT's .

Comment: Are you trying to import `C:\Users\The_T\Downloads\generative-art-node-main\index.js`? Does this file exist?

Comment: Check if you're misspelling module name or path? If it's a third party module then make sure it is installed!

Comment: So I am trying to locate the "C:\Users\The_T\Downloads\generative-art-node-main\index.js  .. I am trying to just run the "node index.js: to start the generating part, I already have everything installed as needed but it keeps saying module not found, yet I have the files all together in the same folder.